# Restore mysql from database snapshot

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, restore

I have a folder containing the snapshot taken from a database.

They are all in the format organisation_product_tablename.sql.

How can I restore them back into the database?

EDIT 1:

I managed to restore all the files, but one with:

```
ls -1 *.sql | awk '{ print "source",$0 }' | mysql --batch -u root -p databaseName
```

The only one that is giving problems fails with an this error:

```
ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 346 in file: 'org_sugar_routines.sql': The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist.
```

This is the Head of the file:

```
USE `organisation_product`;

-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.13, for Win32 (x86)
--
-- Host: 10.10.0.10    Database: organisation_product
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version     5.1.60-community

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Temporary table structure for view `vw_contact_insurance`
--
```

When I checked that line in the file I found that in the file marked as error there is this:

```
/*!50013 DEFINER=`root`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
```

When I run this query

```
mysql> SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

I obtain this:

```
+----------------+----------------+
| USER()         | CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Isn't this the root user? I have it as the admin user in the DB. So, what's the problem here?

Comment: Is this a binary file or a text file ?

Comment: Multiple text files

Comment: I need to see the first 22 lines one of the files. Please run `head -22 organisation_product_tablename.sql` and post the output.

Comment: BTW please run this two queries for me: `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();` and `SELECT CONCAT(QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host)) FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root';` and show the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you restored the tables. Your issue seems to be the owner of either a view or a stored procedure

You need to replace all occurrences of

```
`root`@`%`
```

in the file with

```
`root`@`localhost`
```

I would not recommend creating the user `root@'%'` as that would allow root to have remote access.

Since `root@'%'` is the owner of the routines, I will create `root@'%'` like `root@localhost`

Please run the following:

```
CREATE TABLE mysql.user_root LIKE mysql.user;
INSERT INTO mysql.user_root
SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root' and host='localhost';
UPDATE mysql.user_root SET host='%';
REPLACE INTO mysql.user SELECT * FROM mysql.user_root;
DROP TABLE mysql.user_root;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thanks Rolando. What does % mean in this context?

Comment: The `%` is a wildcard character. The user `root@'%'` means that root can connect to MySQL from anywhere remotely (provided 3306 is open through the firewall). The user `root@localhost` means root can only connect via the socket file on the local box. If you have the user `root@'10.80.30.%'`, then root can only connect from that netblock. To see all defined users and hosts run `SELECT CONCAT(QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host)) FROM mysql.user;`

Comment: Keep in mind that `root@'%'` and `root@localhost` are two separate users. They can have separate passwords if desired.

Comment: I need to create the root@'%', since I will have to reimport the tables on the original environments. How do I create it?

Comment: I'll add that to my answer, give me a couple of minutes ...

Comment: After this I have been able to import the last sql dump, thanks a lot